# In WPF, when is the constructor for a View object (MVVM pattern) called?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In the example application found in the following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

In the CustomerView View, if you put a breakpoint in the constructor for that view, the breakpoint is hit the first time. For subsequent instances of that UserControl displayed, the constructor is not called again.

Two questions:

1. What is the reason for this?
2. Where can I place code I want to be executed every time a new CustomerView is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason that the view is just created once, is that its in a TabControl/HeaderedContentControl .

if you use a listbox, you will see that every time a new viewmodel is added, a new view is created too.

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Workspaces}">
 </ListBox>
```

instead of

```
 <HeaderedContentControl 
      Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
      Header="Workspaces"
      Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}"
      />
```

EDIT:

> Where can I place code I want to be executed every time a new CustomerView is created?

if you use DataTemplates you will never create a new view by yourself. you just create a new VM/object, which then is displayed as the DataTemplate.

if you want create the views by yourself you have to go "view first" approach and then add the right ViewModel to the created view.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The problem I am trying to solve is this: Each tab represents a ViewModel. Now the ViewModel might be doing things in the background. Now if I need the frontend to display messages to the user, the ViewModel should let the View know when and what to display through an event or something similar. But if you have lets say three ViewModels, and only one View, then only one of the ViewModels can have it's messages displayed, depending on which tab you are.

Comment: the view should just show what the viewmodel want to be shown. so if your viewmodel has a property called "MyMessage" and you fill(via Dispatcher!) this property in a long background thread in your viewmodel. it will be shown in your view. you did not need special events, its all about binding and INotifyPropertyChanged. btw you dont have just only one view!! you have just ONE DATATEMPLATE. that you just "see" one view in this example its the behavior of the tabcontrol. take a listbox instead and you will see your 3 views :)

Comment: let the other stackoverflow'ers know what your answer is please.

Comment: The answer is that the TabControl behaves in a way that is unexpected (as described here), and you simply have to work around that.

Answer (score 2):

Only one `CustomerView` is created. When you change the `CustomerViewModel`, it doesn't create a new `CustomerView`, it reuses the existing one.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand correctly. It creates a CustomerView. When you create another one, it created another tab. When you switch between the tabs, it uses the SAME view it created for both tabs, it just switches the bindings to the ViewModel around each time?

Comment: Another question, can someone point me to documentaion on MSDN or something describing this behaviour?

Comment: @Bertus van Zyl, yes, it reuses the same view for all tabs. Since only one tab is visible at one time, there is no need to instantiate several views. I don't think it is described explicitly in the documentation...